# Как в одном ajax запросе отправить текстовые данные формы и загруженный файл?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Имею форму вида

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="someClass">
  <input type="text" name="userName">
  <input type="text" name="userEmail">
  <input type="text" name="userPassword1">
  <input type="text" name="userPassword2">
  <input type="file" name="avatar">
  <button type="submit" id="sumbitForm1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Пытаюсь отправить ajax запрос на сервер следующим образом:

```
$('#submitForm1').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './sign-up.php',
            data: $('form .card').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 10000,
            beforeSend: function(){/*some code*/},
            succes: function(){/*some code*/},
            error: function(){/*some code*/},
            complete: function(){/*some code*/},
        });
    }
```

Проблема в том, что при выводе в консоль `$('form .card').serialize()` , я вижу строку вида `userName=asdfasdf&userEmail=test%40email.com&password1=asdf&password2=asdf`
То есть, как я понимаю - файл на сервер не попадает. Как это решить?

Comment: Вот правильный пример https://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-submit-a-multipart-form/

Comment: @Andrii, можете объяснить что значит эта строка `var form = $('#signupForm')[0];`
А именно, зачем в конце добавляется `[0]` ведь такой id, у меня во всем документе только один. А без `[0]` все равно не работает :(

Comment: `$('#signupForm')` - вернет тебе массив с 1 элементом, а тебе надо менно этот элемент чтобы скормить его в FormData. `$('#signupForm')[0]` равносильна `document.getElementById('signupForm')`

Comment: @Andrii , проблема в том что с , `dataType: 'json'` данный пример не работает. При отправке ajax - запроса срабатывает error (200, parsererror). Хотя файл успешно загружается на сервер

Comment: А зачем тебе `dataType: 'json'`? Чем тебя не устраивает простой тип? Если ты хочешь отправлять json. Тебе тогда надо отдельно файл отправлять отдельно остальные данные и в итоге у тебя 2 запроса будет.

Comment: @RomanAndreev Опция `dataType` - это вид возвращаемых с сервера (а не отправляемых на сервер) данных. Что Вы возвращаете?